# Data rotation in DB2

Tags: java, database, database-design, db2, data-migration

The data for reprocessing requests from the previous week gets moved to a back up table on  due to which I am unable to reprocess failures that occurs during the weekend.

For a particular table, we have three different identical versions. Lets say, we have table1 to store the status and id of the documents. So we have three identical versions of Table1.

Table1_A

Table1_B

Table1_C

`Table1_A` will be active for a week and will store all records and on weekend, a script is run and after that `Table1_A` will be inactive and `table1_B` (which is empty) will take its place as active table for the week. `Table1_A` will retain data from the previous week. The following weekend the script will make `Table1_C` active, `Table1_B` will retain its data from the previous week and `Table1_A` will remove all its data. Same process will repeat every week.

Since the data pertaining to the previous week is in a table that is not active anymore, we are unable to troubleshoot any failures from the previous week.

I have though about copying the previous weeks data from the previous active table to the new active table. The new active table instead of being empty now will have data from previous week.

So, my question is what is a good way to copy this data?

And what are things that I need to worry about while copying this data?

Also, is there a better way to resolve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The described solution is very inflexible.
You do not describe the reason for doing this but I would urgently recommend to have a look at partitioning Range Partitioning will give you SQL performance and fast roll out of data if this is a concern.

When data resides in in Table1_a while Table1_b is active - table1_a is still there and could be queried. It may be offline from an application point of view but not from a database point of view.

Without any more business background information I just could recommend to check out table partitioning.

Comment: Any failed requests can only be reprocessed using the transactionID of the original failed request. The reprocessing occurs through the application. Since the data including the transactionID from the previous week is in the inactive table, reprocessing can not be performed for failures from previous week.